# fatal error/ EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when using the .jar file

Tags: java, exception, jar, fatal-error, xuggler

i'm using xuggler to read audio from video files.The most videos are correctly read in, but some lead to an fatal error:

```
    A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000067626520, pid=3156, tid=5060
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_77-b03) (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.77-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000067626520
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

My problem is,when i run it from netbeans,everything works fine.When i'm using the .jar file in the dist folder the program closes immediatly.
(I'm using the same video file for the reading)

Is there anything i can adjust, so that the .jar file behaves the same way the "run file" behaves? compiler prefferences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error detected in Eclipse when using Xuggle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942958/fatal-error-detected-in-eclipse-when-using-xuggle)

Comment: but why is there any difference between .jar and the run "file" from netbeans at all? i just want to understand why it could behave otherwise?

Comment: There is no significant difference between running a java program as class file and as jar. While executing as jar manually, some dependency might be missing or corrupted could lead to this problem. Please check the dependencies added in the class path are good and compatible with JVM and your requirements.

For your reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922681/differences-between-java-cp-and-java-jar